# Lagrangian multiplier: role of the constraint sign

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, lagrange-multipliers

I am beginner learning Lagrange multipliers with [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Consider:

maximize $f(x,y)$ subject to $g(x,y) = 0$

I understand that to maximize I must follow the gradient $\nabla {_{x, y}}^{}f$. I also understand that gradient of the constraint $\nabla{_{x, y}}^{}g$ must be collinear to  $\nabla {_{x, y}}^{}f$ (to check whether $\nabla {_{x, y}}^{}f$ projection  to the constraint line equal to 0).

But I totally misunderstood role of the sign in the equality.

$\nabla {_{x, y}}f = -\lambda  \nabla {_{x, y}}g$

where $\lambda > 0$ and we maximizing $f(x,y)$

See picture from wiki:

[image]

I could imagine $g'(x,y) = 0$ which give same set of points ${x,y}$ (red line) as $g(x,y) = 0$ but have just the opposite gradient (opposite red arrows direction) and in this case my maximum of $f$ will become minimum?!

Comment: It is helpful to think of $\lambda$ as a penalty, since the method is used for minimization *or* maximization. Basically, no matter what values of $x, y$ you obtain to optimize your functional, the $\lambda$ will be an arbitrarily large penalty against that value so long as $g(x, y) \ne c$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no sign restriction for the Lagrange multiplier of an equality constraint.  Lagrange multipliers of inequality constraints do have a sign restriction.

You should really look at the Karush-Kuhn-tucker conditions if you want to understand Lagrange multipliers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions . Realistically, you will need to study a book or course notes. Here is a high quality book available as a free pdf from the author's website http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ .  If you can make it through chapter 5, you'll be in good shape.

Comment: I knew it! I felt that wiki do not tell me everything I should know. So another words minus lambda or not - doesnt metter...

Comment: Yes, lose that article like a bad habit.  Nevertheless, I didn't see where the article stated anywhere that there was a sign restriction on the Lagrange multiplier for the g(x,y) = c constraint, so perhaps you saw such a sign restriction elsewhere, in conjunction with an inequality constraint, and mistakenly assumed that it applied to the Lagrange multiplier of an equality constraint.