# Inequality constrained optimization, what is the intuition?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, optimization

In an introductory lecture to SVM (Support vector machine), we are given a review of The **inequality** constrainted optimization. Which is summarized in a single lecture slide. The slide reads as the following:

---

**The problem**

$$
\min\limits_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(\mathbf{x}) \quad \text{ subject to } \quad h(\mathbf{x}) \geq c\,.
$$

Conceptually the problem is solved as the following:

1. Write the Lagrangian $$L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) - \lambda(h(\mathbf{x}) - c)\,.$$
2. Introduce the dual function 
   $$
   d(\lambda) = \inf\limits_{\mathbf{x}} L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda)\,.
   $$
3. Solve the dual problem 
   $$
   \lambda^* = \text{arg}\max\limits_{\lambda} d(\lambda)\quad  \text{  subject to } \lambda \geq 0\,.
   $$
4. The optimal $\mathbf{x}$ (assuming strong dality) is $$\mathbf{x} = \text{arg}\inf\limits_{\mathbf{x}} L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda^*)\,.$$

When $f$ is convex function and $h(\mathbf{x}) \geq 0$ defines convex region of space, this gives the global optimum.

---

**Question**

What I am looking for is not necessarily rigorous explanation but rather **intuitive interpretation of why each of the steps indeed goes in the "right direction"** so that the above interpretation indeed leads to the optimal minimum under the constraints.

---

*In contrast*: for **equality** constrained optimization I do understand the intuition behind the Lagrangian. To outline, the derivatives of the Lagrangian introduce the requirement that at the solution the gradients of the constraint and the objective be parallel.

**EDITED** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223235/please-explain-the-intuition-behind-the-dual-problem-in-optimization) already contain the answer I was looking for, see answer there by @Dan Piponi.

Comment: Not quite related to your question, but I need to  have a quick review of equality constrained optimization, do you also have a lecture slide for that? =P

Comment: @Gigili. On the equality constrained optimization the slide does not say that much on the intuition - take the derivative and solve for the $\lambda$ and $\mathbf{x}$. In more details:  $\frac{\partial L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda)}{\partial x_i} = 0\, i=1,2, \ldots, n$ will give you a curve $\mathbf{x} = \gamma(\lambda)$. Reintroduce the constraint $h(\gamma(\mathbf{x})) = c$ , solve for $\lambda^*$ and get the optimal $\mathbf{x} =  \gamma(\lambda^*)$. Also you might want to look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169194/lagrangian-multiplier-role-of-the-constraint-sign)

Comment: Yeah, I need the details of those mathematical steps. Thanks anyway.